# Http Error 500 Azure Websites Deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I've published an app to `Azure` for the first time. When I go to the site I get an `HTTP 500 error` saying

> The page isn't working.  *****.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request.

Looking at the Live Metrics Stream on the Azure Portal it says

> Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK

This is a .Net Core app.

When I published it there were no errors.  It said the build and publishing were successful.  I'm not sure what other information I can give to help someone help me resolve this.

Below is an error from the Azure Portal:
[image]

Comment: Any information in Application Insights? Seems like Azure broke your app during searching the SDK.

Comment: To isolate the issue, just check to see if it is due to the telemetry data configured  (client-side vs server-side) -https://learn.microsoft.com//azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript

Comment: @BowmanZhu What should I be looking for?  I found 2 GET requests in the Performance tab in Application Insights.  The timestamps are within 1 second of each other.  And it says those requests were successful with a response code of 200.  The request URL is the url of the website although, it says 'http' instead of 'https'.  Visual Studio says the URL starts with "https".

Comment: @BowmanZhu I added a screenshot of an error message

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT I added a screenshot of an error message

Comment: @QHafeez Please don't show the error in image. It is important when asking questions on stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code in your `.csproj` file, then deploy to Azure, test whether it can be solved.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I got some more info from the App Services section.  I wasn't able to paste the whole error  

Session ID
407a9d01819542598a3048c89096e9d5                           

Resource ID
/subscriptions/09320f0b-ce2b-458e-968b-ab1387aac1fe/resourceGroups/WorkoutTracker20191119063801ResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.web/sites/aspWorkoutTracker                                    

Extension
Not available
                                                   
Content
ActivityLogBlade
                                 
Error code
--
       
Error reason
ErrorLoadingExtensionAndDefinition

Comment: @QHafeez Sorry, I didn't notice your reply. Can it works fine on local?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue as well.  Assuming you have no errors in the deploy:
[image: No build or deploy errors]

Restarting the app on the portal worked for me.

[image: Restart app in Azure]

This may be more than you need, but, I also add a health check to the app looking for bad instances to automatically remove them.
[image: Health Check]

HTH